# Simple connection from through hole pad to through hole pad

Tags: pcb, altium, layout

[image]

I am making a convertor board in Altium where some lines need to be switched with transistors while others just go from pad to pad and nothing else.

I tried to draw a wire in the schematic and added net names which are not showing in the PCB. I can draw a connection from pad to pad without net names but can't draw polygon pour.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you add some screenshots of what you have and what you are trying to do?

Comment: Sure, i have 2 pads that i want to connect have no net and also do polygon pour over them

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yFclbq8sGxIertBlvC3OAsUg_Ajm62eG/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please add them as images to your post, don't link to an external site in the comments.

Comment: Added, please see above

Comment: Your picture is from the layout, not the schematic.  Are you trying to draw a PCB layout without starting from a schematic?  The normal way is to draw the schematic diagram in Altium, then do the PCB layout from the schematic diagram.  That takes care of all your problems with net names.

Comment: I have the net line with wire before it was doing nothing, now i added a pad with pin, worked out fine....thanks for getting back to me